# Images uploading corrupt

Tags: image, upload

Can anyone suggest why my images are uploading either blank (PNGs) or look like static (JPGS)?

Example here - https://cookproperty.co.nz/admin/resources/assetthumbs/904/200?d=1636447193

I don't usually work with craft and have transferred this over from another developer as I'm just hosting so not sure if that transfer would have an effect?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I suggest double-checking that the new server meets Craft's requirements, especially in terms of ImageMagick and/or GD. You can run an automated check using the wizard: https://github.com/craftcms/server-check, Or manually review the requirements here: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/requirements.html

Comment: Hey @james - Seems to be something to do with indexing as the client clicked the update asset indexing button and now most of the images on the site are broken in the same way -.- can you advise what might have caused thaT?